# How to call Button.performClick in Android JUnit test case?

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm new to Android Testing stuff. I'd like to test if clicking a button will open up a corresponding activity or not. I did some research and found out that I will need to use ActivityManager to do the checking.

Problem is, I can't get the "clicking" part working. I'm trying to use `Button.performClick()`.

Initially I just called this function, and got an error saying that I can't do this in the current thread. After some googling I found out that I need to call it in the UI thread, and came across `runOnUiThread(Runnable r) method`.

The button I'm trying to click is `_helloButton_`. This is obtained in the `_setUp()_ method`. I did `_assertNotNull_` check on this to make sure it's there.

Within a test method, I call

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            helloButton.requestFocus();
        }
    });
helloButton.performClick();
```

and I get a NPE at the line calling `requestFocus()`.

Next I tried

```
mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            helloButton.performClick();
        }
    });
```

and still get the same null pointer exception.

On the JUnit perspective, I get this message

```
Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''. Check device logcat for details
```

And the stackTrace look like this.

```
    08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at com.example.helloworldmk2.test.HelloWorldMK2Test$1.run(HelloWorldMK2Test.java:57)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
08-05 19:03:11.922: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(578):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Line 57 is where I'm calling the `helloButton.performClick()`.

I'm not sure why I'm getting NPE; assertNotNull passes without problem. If you can help me with this issue, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'm subclassing ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 for this particular test class.

EDIT2: Logcat spews out some errors before NPE happens.

I see

08-05 20:08:54.702: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(754): ERROR: thread attach failed

and

08-05 20:08:58.642: ERROR/gralloc(52): [unregister] handle 0x3e1b28 still locked (state=40000001)

Comment: For clarification, you want to press a button that will trigger the launch of a new activity?

Comment: yes. The button has a onClickListener, which starts another activity.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can annotate your test to run on UI thread:

```
@UiThreadTest
public void testNoErrorInCapitalization() {
    final String msg = "this is a sample";
    mMessage.setText(msg);
    mCapitalize.performClick();
    final String actual = mMessage.getText().toString();
    final String notExpectedRegexp = "(?i:ERROR)";
    assertNotContainsRegex("Capitalization found error:",
        notExpectedRegexp, actual);
}
```

This is an example taken from [Android Application Testing Guide](http://www.packtpub.com/android-application-testing-guide/book).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use runTestOnUiThread() method like below

```
public void testHelloButton() throws Throwable{
        runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                helloButton.performClick();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You are taking a far too difficult approach to a simple problem... essentially you need code structured like this *BEWARE, this is pseudo-code and will NOT work*

```
public void myOnClickListener(View source) {

  switch source.getId() {
  case R.id.Your_Button_Name_In_Xml :
    Intent MyNewActivity = new Intent(this, MyNewClass.class);
    startActivity(MyNewActivity);
  }
}
```

check this out http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/opening-new-screen-in-android.html

Comment: I know how that method works, but that's not really what I need to do here. This is a JUnit test case; all the button click listeners are already defined. I simply need to be able to click it within the test case method.