# Unit testing a method declared inside a method

Tags: java, android, junit

I have an Android application, where inside an onCreate() method of an Activity a button is defined to have an onClick method. In code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /.../
        buttonSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.store_button_save);
        buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveEditor(v);
            }
        });     
    /.../
}
```

My question is, how can I call this nested method onCLick() from an Android unit test? `myActivity.onClick(myButton)` does not work, since onClick() is not a method defined in the activity itself.

Btw, I should not be changing any original source code for my tests.

Comment: send a click event to the buttonSave to test the onClick event handler.

Comment: @DwB: could you give me an example how you would do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test this by not creating such an anoynmous class.
Instead create a normal inner class, and assign a new instance to to the listener:

```
public static class MyClickListener implements OnClickListener {
Editor editor;
public MyClickListener(Editor e) {
   this editor= e;
}
public void onClick(View v) {
  editor.saveEditor(v);
}
}

buttonSave.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener());
```

In JuniTest

```
    public void testOnClickListener() {
     Editor e = new Editor();
    MyClickListener l = new MyClickListener(e);
    l.onClick();
    // however you check for correct result
    assertTrue(checkSaveEditor(e));

    }
```

But why not just write unitest for method `saveEditor()` only?
This is  sufficient, you can rely that `onClick()` works.

Comment: So, you say I should change the original code? It is not my code and if possible I would avoid modifying it. Would there be another solution? If no, could you give an example of your solution? Thanks!

Comment: if you want to test it as a direct unit test, then there is no other solution. but for simple code not always a direct test is neccesry. indirect test are an alternative (by calling onclick). and Yes if the originsl author has not desgined for testability, you have to improve the code.

Comment: sure, you are making a point. Could you give a code example how I could implement the solution you suggested in your answer?

Comment: see above in my answer

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer. The reason why I don't test `saveEditor()` directly is because it is private and therefore should not be tested directly. Also, using plain Mockito it is also not possible (according to my knowledge). Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere here. :)

Comment: If you want to test saveEditor() make it protected, this is the best method because to get the best code quality direct unit tests are obligate

Answer (score 0):

The  onClick method is defined inside an anonymous class, so you cannot directly invoke it. Instead you need trigger the click event from the outer class. Don't know much about Android development but the following post explains how to test such as scenario using ActivityManager to simulate a button click with @UIthreadTest annotation. [How to call Button.performClick in Android JUnit test case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961754/how-to-call-button-performclick-in-android-junit-test-case)

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, the offered solution will not work, since @UIthreadTest is not allowed for ActivityUnitTestCase which I am using for activity testing. It works good for ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2, but that test class had another scope.